# Oracle SQL or PL/SQL Validation on overlap number range on person age

Tags: sql, oracle, validation, plsql

So at the moment I am developing application where I need to validate results based on the number range of person age. If the numbers overlap need to throw error.
***Edit:*** Updating post as per @Littlefoot question asked. In below example row#1 exists in the table and based on that valid and invalid conditions determined.
Below is the valid and invalid conditions:

```
+----+------+----------+--------+
| ID | NAME | FROM_AGE | TO_AGE |           
+----+------+----------+--------+
|  1 | Kim  |       26 |     28 | -- Valid   
|  2 | Kim  |       20 |     25 | -- Valid   
|  3 | Kim  |          |     16 | -- Valid   
|  4 | Kim  |       29 |        | -- Valid   
|  5 | Kim  |       19 |     22 | -- Invalid 
|  6 | Kim  |       27 |     28 | -- Invalid 
|  7 | Kim  |       18 |     30 | -- Invalid 
|  8 | Kim  |       26 |     32 | -- Invalid 
+----+------+----------+--------+
```

Valid conditions: Person age - "From Age" and "To Age" should not overlap for the same person
Invalid conditions: Person age is within From and To range
Data provided above is sample. In real time there will be different persons.

Have hosted this on apex.oracle.com and still providing SQL script below.
URL: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1
Workspace: richaferna
username: demo
password: demo1234

Frontend URL: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=77049:2

App ID: 77049
App Name: PERSON AGE

Below is the SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE "PERSON_AGE" (
    "ID"         NUMBER(5,0),
    "NAME"       VARCHAR2(20),
    "FROM_AGE"   NUMBER(3,0),
    "TO_AGE"     NUMBER(3,0),
    CONSTRAINT  "PERSON_AGE_PK" PRIMARY KEY("ID")
)
/

CREATE SEQUENCE"PERSON_AGE_SEQ" 
/

CREATE TRIGGER "BI_PERSON_AGE"  
  BEFORE INSERT ON "PERSON_AGE"              
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
  IF :NEW."ID" IS NULL THEN
    SELECT "PERSON_AGE_SEQ".nextval INTO :new."ID" FROM sys.dual;
  END IF;
END;
/   

INSERT INTO PERSON_AGE VALUES(1, 'Kim', 26, 28);

INSERT INTO PERSON_AGE VALUES(2, 'Kim', 20, 25);

INSERT INTO PERSON_AGE VALUES(3, 'Kim', 0, 26);

INSERT INTO PERSON_AGE VALUES(4, 'Kim', 29, 0);
```

Below is the No rows returned validation I tried which is not letting even valid data to save:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM "PERSON_AGE" a, "PERSON_AGE" b
 WHERE a.name = b.name
   AND a."TO_AGE" >= b."FROM_AGE"
   AND b."TO_AGE" >= a."FROM_AGE"
```

Thanks,
Richa

Comment: How do you decide which rows are valid and which are not? If row #7 (age in range 18 - 30) was VALID, then all other rows would become INVALID. So, what's the rule?

Comment: @Littlefoot that's good question. I think it should go by first record entered/saved for a person. As per your example, if row #7 is first entered and saved, then yes all other rows would become invalid

Comment: @Littlefoot based on your question, I tried modifying query but still getting error:
select count(*) from PERSON_AGE a, PERSON_AGE b
where a.name = b.name and a.id < b.id
and a.to_age >= b.from_age
and b.to_age >= a.from_age

Answer (score 2):

To ensure overlaps are impossible, you need to:

- Create a `fast refresh on commit` materialized view that counts how many overlaps there are
- Add a check constraint to this to ensure the count is zero

You have to do this check this way. If you (only) do front-end validation, two sessions running at the same time adding the same/overlapping values will not see each-others changes. So you can pass the validation, but still end up with overlaps.

Also note that the MV check happens on commit. So if one transaction adds several rows with one overlap, you'll only find out at the end.

```
create sequence person_age_seq 
/

create table person_age (
  id         number(5,0)
    default on null person_age_seq.nextval,
  name       varchar2(20),
  from_age   number(3,0),
  to_age     number(3,0),
  constraint person_age_pk 
    primary key ( id ),
  constraint person_age_from_before_to
    check ( from_age < to_age )
)
/

create materialized view log on person_age
  with rowid, primary key ( name, from_age, to_age )
  including new values;
 
create materialized view age_count
refresh fast on commit
as
select count(*) c 
from   person_age a, person_age b
where  a.name = b.name
and   (
  ( a.from_age > b.from_age and a.from_age < b.to_age ) or
  ( a.to_age > b.from_age and a.to_age < b.to_age ) or
  ( a.to_age > b.to_age and a.from_age < b.from_age ) 
);

alter materialized view age_count
  add constraint zero_overlap
  check ( c = 0 );

insert into person_age(name, from_age, to_age)
values( 'Kim', 20, 25);
commit;
insert into person_age(name, from_age, to_age)
values( 'Kim', 26, 28);
commit;
insert into person_age(name, from_age, to_age)
values( 'Kim', 28, 30);
commit;
insert into person_age(name, from_age, to_age)
values( 'Kim', 29, 30);
commit;

ORA-12008: error in materialized view or zonemap refresh path
ORA-02290: check constraint (CHRIS.ZERO_OVERLAP) violated

insert into person_age( name, from_age, to_age)
values( 'Kim', 29, 0);

ORA-02290: check constraint (CHRIS.PERSON_AGE_FROM_BEFORE_TO) violated

insert into person_age(name, from_age, to_age)
values( 'Kim', 0, 26);
commit;

ORA-12008: error in materialized view or zonemap refresh path
ORA-02290: check constraint (CHRIS.ZERO_OVERLAP) violated

insert into person_age(name, from_age, to_age)
values( 'Kim', 19, 31);
commit;

ORA-12008: error in materialized view or zonemap refresh path
ORA-02290: check constraint (CHRIS.ZERO_OVERLAP) violated

insert into person_age(name, from_age, to_age)
values( 'Kim', 21, 24);
commit;

ORA-12008: error in materialized view or zonemap refresh path
ORA-02290: check constraint (CHRIS.ZERO_OVERLAP) violated

select *
from   person_age a
order by from_age, to_age;

ID    NAME   FROM_AGE    TO_AGE   
    1 Kim          20        25 
    2 Kim          26        28 
    3 Kim          28        30
```

I've ignored `null` for simplicity. Your sample table suggests these are possible, so you'll need to change the query to account for this. Personally I would have said `(null, 26)` overlapped with `(20, 25)`, though you've said these are both valid.

PS - please avoid using triggers to assign primary key values; use `default (on null)` instead

Comment: thank you for kind response and for sharing knowledge. (null,26) was a typo. Sorry. It's (null,16) and have updated the post.

Comment: Added Function returning boolean with below code in Oracle APEX validation and is working fine.  It's the null values am not able to figure it out. Thank you @Chris Saxon for your help.
declare 
a_count number(5);
begin
select count(*) into a_count 
from   person_age a, person_age b
where  a.name = b.name
and   (
  ( a.from_age > b.from_age and a.from_age < b.to_age ) or
  ( a.to_age > b.from_age and a.to_age < b.to_age ) or
  ( a.to_age > b.to_age and a.from_age < b.from_age ) 
);
if a_count > 0 then 
return false;
else 
return true;
end if;
end;

Comment: @Richa Just to re-iterate - if you **only** do this in APEX validation, you can still end up with overlaps! To ensure you avoid this, create the MV as well. One way to deal with nulls is to `nvl` them with suitable bounds. For `from_age`, zero should work (no one can have a negative age, right?); for `to_age` choose a suitably high value

Comment: Thank You Chris. This is the first time I got to know know about Materialized Views. Will implement the same and study more on MV.